# How much memory is an empty JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

**Option A:**

```
myobj = {
    a: 'a',
    a1: 'a1',
    a2: 'a2',
    a2a: 'a2a',
    a2b: 'a2b',
    a3: 'a3',
    a3a: 'a3a',
    a3a1: 'a3a1',
    a3a2: 'a3a2',
    b: 'b',
    // ...
};
```

vs.  **Option B:**

```
myobj = {
    a: {
        a1: 'a1',
        a2: {
            a2a: 'a2a',
            a2b: 'a2b'
        },
        a3: {
            a3a: {
                a3a1: 'a3a1',
                a3a2: 'a3a2'
            }
        }
    },
    b: { ... }
};
```

I'm weighing this as a design decision.  Here's a simpler case:

**Option A:**

```
eventHandler: {
    triggerObj: triggerObj,
    triggerAction: triggerObj.someMethod,
    responseObj: responseObj,
    responseAction: responseObj.someMethod
}
```

vs. **Option B:**

```
eventHandler: {
    trigger: {
        obj: triggerObj,
        action: triggerObj.someMethod
    },
    response: {
        obj: responseObj,
        action: responseObj.someMethod
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is like the eye doctor:  *they're so close, it doesn't really matter.*  However, thought I'd see if there are any solid reasons for performance, or just for semantic/readability/other.

Relating back to the question title: how many extra object braces would be necessary to have a notable performance issue?  I doubt even a few 1000 or even a 1,000,000 would matter much :-\

Comment: Doctors know a thing or two. Especially _eye doctors_.

Comment: Yea right, the machines do all the work

Comment: Why don't you create a million elements each way, and look at the memory graph in Developer Tools to see how they compare?

Comment: Do you have a performance issue? If not, you're pre-optimizing, and you're making your code less coherent in the process.

Comment: @Barmar Yea, I should learn how to do that.

Comment: Agree with @Aesthete. First do it the way that fits the application design best. If there's a memory issue, optimize it then.

Comment: The memory/performance thing is more of a curiousity.  Maybe there's some reason why the JavaScript processor has to climb a mountain every time it hits a curly brace, or something...  I'm also curious if there are any other side effects, such as namespace issues, or.. I dunno.

Comment: @MikeLewis Parsing is generally done once and is *very* fast (although V8 might favor to re-parse code in the case of functions). For *very very very* large object literals this may cause undesirable behavior (and there are some SO posts .. where large is in excess of tens of thousands of elements in a single object literal). But not for anything sane. Likewise, small objects (especially with static names) are *well optimized* by modern engines.

Comment: Run a benchmark and you tell us the answer

Comment: ty @user2864740, feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and did it. I created an empty object, and into it I put 1 million empty objects. Then I opened profiler.

```
Object count: 1,011,296
Shallow size: 12,202,312
Retained size: 14,434,484
```

So each empty JavaScript object is about 12 bytes. I also tried it with empty array objects:

```
Array count: 1,000,725
Shallow size: 32,023,200
Retained size: 32,034,880
```

Empty array objects take up about 32 bytes.

Comment: Good point but do you think array objects behave differently? Arrays are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: I think it's entirely possible that an empty array occupies a different amount of memory than an empty object does.